# How can i solve this problem? Root Signature doesn't match Vertex Shader:

Tags: c++, hlsl, directx-12

While adding the code to render the shadows, I ran into a question.

In Debug of output view selection,
The following error message pops up:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0arL.png)

Here is the shader code I added.

```
struct VS_LIGHTING_INPUT
{
    float3 position : POSITION;
    float3 normal : NORMAL;
};

struct VS_LIGHTING_OUTPUT
{
    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
    float3 positionW : POSITION;
    float3 normalW : NORMAL;
};

VS_LIGHTING_OUTPUT VSLighting(VS_LIGHTING_INPUT input)
{
    VS_LIGHTING_OUTPUT output;

    output.normalW = mul(input.normal, (float3x3)gmtxGameObject);
    output.positionW = (float3)mul(float4(input.position, 1.0f), gmtxGameObject);
    output.position = mul(mul(float4(output.positionW, 1.0f), gmtxView), gmtxProjection);

    return(output);
}

float4 PSLighting(VS_LIGHTING_OUTPUT input) : SV_TARGET
{
    input.normalW = normalize(input.normalW);
    float4 uvs[MAX_SHADOW_LIGHTS];
    float4 cIllumination = shadowLighting(input.positionW, input.normalW, false, uvs);

    //  return(cIllumination);
    return(float4(input.normalW * 0.5f + 0.5f, 1.0f));
}
//==================================================================================================

struct PS_DEPTH_OUTPUT
{
    float fzPosition : SV_Target;
    float fDepth : SV_Depth;
};

PS_DEPTH_OUTPUT PSDepthWriteShader(VS_LIGHTING_OUTPUT input)
{
    PS_DEPTH_OUTPUT output;

    output.fzPosition = input.position.z;
    output.fDepth = input.position.z;

    return(output);
}

//==================================================================================================
struct VS_SHADOW_MAP_OUTPUT
{
    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
    float3 positionW : POSITION;
    float3 normalW : NORMAL;

    float4 uvs[MAX_SHADOW_LIGHTS] : TEXCOORD0;
};

VS_SHADOW_MAP_OUTPUT VSShadowMapShadow(VS_LIGHTING_INPUT input)
{
    VS_SHADOW_MAP_OUTPUT output = (VS_SHADOW_MAP_OUTPUT)0;

    float4 positionW = mul(float4(input.position, 1.0f), gmtxGameObject);
    output.positionW = positionW.xyz;
    output.position = mul(mul(positionW, gmtxView), gmtxProjection);
    output.normalW = mul(float4(input.normal, 0.0f), gmtxGameObject).xyz;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SHADOW_LIGHTS; i++)
    {
        if (gcbToLightSpaces[i].f4Position.w != 0.0f) output.uvs[i] = mul(positionW, gcbToLightSpaces[i].mtxToTexture);
    }

    return(output);
}

float4 PSShadowMapShadow(VS_SHADOW_MAP_OUTPUT input) : SV_TARGET
{
    float4 cIllumination = shadowLighting(input.positionW, normalize(input.normalW), true, input.uvs);

    return(cIllumination);
}
```

The root signature is set as follows.

```
ID3D12RootSignature* CStage::CreateGraphicsRootSignature(ID3D12Device* pd3dDevice)
{
    ID3D12RootSignature* pd3dGraphicsRootSignature = NULL;

    D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE pd3dDescriptorRanges[8];

    pd3dDescriptorRanges[0].RangeType = D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE_TYPE_SRV;
    pd3dDescriptorRanges[0].NumDescriptors = 1;
    pd3dDescriptorRanges[0].BaseShaderRegister = 6; //t6: gtxtAlbedoTexture
    pd3dDescriptorRanges[0].RegisterSpace = 0;
    pd3dDescriptorRanges[0].OffsetInDescriptorsFromTableStart = D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE_OFFSET_APPEND;

    pd3dDescriptorRanges[1].RangeType = D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE_TYPE_SRV;
    pd3dDescriptorRanges[1].NumDescriptors = 1;
    pd3dDescriptorRanges[1].BaseShaderRegister = 7; //t7: gtxtSpecularTexture
    pd3dDescriptorRanges[1].RegisterSpace = 0;
    pd3dDescriptorRanges[1].OffsetInDescriptorsFromTableStart = D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE_OFFSET_APPEND;

    pd3dDescriptorRanges[2].RangeType = D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE_TYPE_SRV;
    pd3dDescriptorRanges[2].NumDescriptors = 1;
    pd3dDescriptorRanges[2].BaseShaderRegister = 8; //t8: gtxtNormalTexture
    pd3dDescriptorRanges[2].RegisterSpace = 0;
    pd3dDescriptorRanges[2].OffsetInDescriptorsFromTableStart = D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE_OFFSET_APPEND;

    pd3dDescriptorRanges[3].RangeType = D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE_TYPE_SRV;
    pd3dDescriptorRanges[3].NumDescriptors = 1;
    pd3dDescriptorRanges[3].BaseShaderRegister = 9; //t9: gtxtMetallicTexture
    pd3dDescriptorRanges[3].RegisterSpace = 0;
    pd3dDescriptorRanges[3].OffsetInDescriptorsFromTableStart = D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE_OFFSET_APPEND;

    pd3dDescriptorRanges[4].RangeType = D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE_TYPE_SRV;
    pd3dDescriptorRanges[4].NumDescriptors = 1;
    pd3dDescriptorRanges[4].BaseShaderRegister = 10; //t10: gtxtEmissionTexture
    pd3dDescriptorRanges[4].RegisterSpace = 0;
    pd3dDescriptorRanges[4].OffsetInDescriptorsFromTableStart = D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE_OFFSET_APPEND;

    pd3dDescriptorRanges[5].RangeType = D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE_TYPE_SRV;
    pd3dDescriptorRanges[5].NumDescriptors = 1;
    pd3dDescriptorRanges[5].BaseShaderRegister = 11; //t11: gtxtEmissionTexture
    pd3dDescriptorRanges[5].RegisterSpace = 0;
    pd3dDescriptorRanges[5].OffsetInDescriptorsFromTableStart = D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE_OFFSET_APPEND;

    pd3dDescriptorRanges[6].RangeType = D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE_TYPE_SRV;
    pd3dDescriptorRanges[6].NumDescriptors = 1;
    pd3dDescriptorRanges[6].BaseShaderRegister = 12; //t12: gtxtEmissionTexture
    pd3dDescriptorRanges[6].RegisterSpace = 0;
    pd3dDescriptorRanges[6].OffsetInDescriptorsFromTableStart = D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE_OFFSET_APPEND;

    pd3dDescriptorRanges[7].RangeType = D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE_TYPE_SRV;
    pd3dDescriptorRanges[7].NumDescriptors = MAX_DEPTH_TEXTURES;
    pd3dDescriptorRanges[7].BaseShaderRegister = 2; //Depth Buffer
    pd3dDescriptorRanges[7].RegisterSpace = 0;
    pd3dDescriptorRanges[7].OffsetInDescriptorsFromTableStart = D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE_OFFSET_APPEND;


    D3D12_ROOT_PARAMETER pd3dRootParameters[14];

    pd3dRootParameters[0].ParameterType = D3D12_ROOT_PARAMETER_TYPE_CBV;
    pd3dRootParameters[0].Descriptor.ShaderRegister = 1; //Camera
    pd3dRootParameters[0].Descriptor.RegisterSpace = 0;
    pd3dRootParameters[0].ShaderVisibility = D3D12_SHADER_VISIBILITY_ALL;

    pd3dRootParameters[1].ParameterType = D3D12_ROOT_PARAMETER_TYPE_32BIT_CONSTANTS;
    pd3dRootParameters[1].Constants.Num32BitValues = 33;
    pd3dRootParameters[1].Constants.ShaderRegister = 2; //GameObject
    pd3dRootParameters[1].Constants.RegisterSpace = 0;
    pd3dRootParameters[1].ShaderVisibility = D3D12_SHADER_VISIBILITY_ALL;

    pd3dRootParameters[2].ParameterType = D3D12_ROOT_PARAMETER_TYPE_CBV;
    pd3dRootParameters[2].Descriptor.ShaderRegister = 4; //Lights
    pd3dRootParameters[2].Descriptor.RegisterSpace = 0;
    pd3dRootParameters[2].ShaderVisibility = D3D12_SHADER_VISIBILITY_ALL;


    pd3dRootParameters[3].ParameterType = D3D12_ROOT_PARAMETER_TYPE_DESCRIPTOR_TABLE;
    pd3dRootParameters[3].DescriptorTable.NumDescriptorRanges = 1;
    pd3dRootParameters[3].DescriptorTable.pDescriptorRanges = &(pd3dDescriptorRanges[0]);
    pd3dRootParameters[3].ShaderVisibility = D3D12_SHADER_VISIBILITY_PIXEL;

    pd3dRootParameters[4].ParameterType = D3D12_ROOT_PARAMETER_TYPE_DESCRIPTOR_TABLE;
    pd3dRootParameters[4].DescriptorTable.NumDescriptorRanges = 1;
    pd3dRootParameters[4].DescriptorTable.pDescriptorRanges = &(pd3dDescriptorRanges[1]);
    pd3dRootParameters[4].ShaderVisibility = D3D12_SHADER_VISIBILITY_PIXEL;

    pd3dRootParameters[5].ParameterType = D3D12_ROOT_PARAMETER_TYPE_DESCRIPTOR_TABLE;
    pd3dRootParameters[5].DescriptorTable.NumDescriptorRanges = 1;
    pd3dRootParameters[5].DescriptorTable.pDescriptorRanges = &(pd3dDescriptorRanges[2]);
    pd3dRootParameters[5].ShaderVisibility = D3D12_SHADER_VISIBILITY_PIXEL;

    pd3dRootParameters[6].ParameterType = D3D12_ROOT_PARAMETER_TYPE_DESCRIPTOR_TABLE;
    pd3dRootParameters[6].DescriptorTable.NumDescriptorRanges = 1;
    pd3dRootParameters[6].DescriptorTable.pDescriptorRanges = &(pd3dDescriptorRanges[3]);
    pd3dRootParameters[6].ShaderVisibility = D3D12_SHADER_VISIBILITY_PIXEL;

    pd3dRootParameters[7].ParameterType = D3D12_ROOT_PARAMETER_TYPE_DESCRIPTOR_TABLE;
    pd3dRootParameters[7].DescriptorTable.NumDescriptorRanges = 1;
    pd3dRootParameters[7].DescriptorTable.pDescriptorRanges = &(pd3dDescriptorRanges[4]);
    pd3dRootParameters[7].ShaderVisibility = D3D12_SHADER_VISIBILITY_PIXEL;

    pd3dRootParameters[8].ParameterType = D3D12_ROOT_PARAMETER_TYPE_DESCRIPTOR_TABLE;
    pd3dRootParameters[8].DescriptorTable.NumDescriptorRanges = 1;
    pd3dRootParameters[8].DescriptorTable.pDescriptorRanges = &(pd3dDescriptorRanges[5]);
    pd3dRootParameters[8].ShaderVisibility = D3D12_SHADER_VISIBILITY_PIXEL;


    pd3dRootParameters[9].ParameterType = D3D12_ROOT_PARAMETER_TYPE_DESCRIPTOR_TABLE;
    pd3dRootParameters[9].DescriptorTable.NumDescriptorRanges = 1;
    pd3dRootParameters[9].DescriptorTable.pDescriptorRanges = &(pd3dDescriptorRanges[6]);
    pd3dRootParameters[9].ShaderVisibility = D3D12_SHADER_VISIBILITY_PIXEL;





    pd3dRootParameters[10].ParameterType = D3D12_ROOT_PARAMETER_TYPE_DESCRIPTOR_TABLE;
    pd3dRootParameters[10].DescriptorTable.NumDescriptorRanges = 1;
    pd3dRootParameters[10].DescriptorTable.pDescriptorRanges = &pd3dDescriptorRanges[7]; //Depth`Buffer
    pd3dRootParameters[10].ShaderVisibility = D3D12_SHADER_VISIBILITY_PIXEL;

    pd3dRootParameters[11].ParameterType = D3D12_ROOT_PARAMETER_TYPE_CBV;
    pd3dRootParameters[11].Descriptor.ShaderRegister = 7; //Skinned Bone Offsets
    pd3dRootParameters[11].Descriptor.RegisterSpace = 0;
    pd3dRootParameters[11].ShaderVisibility = D3D12_SHADER_VISIBILITY_VERTEX;

    pd3dRootParameters[12].ParameterType = D3D12_ROOT_PARAMETER_TYPE_CBV;
    pd3dRootParameters[12].Descriptor.ShaderRegister = 8; //Skinned Bone Transforms
    pd3dRootParameters[12].Descriptor.RegisterSpace = 0;
    pd3dRootParameters[12].ShaderVisibility = D3D12_SHADER_VISIBILITY_VERTEX;


    pd3dRootParameters[13].ParameterType = D3D12_ROOT_PARAMETER_TYPE_CBV;
    pd3dRootParameters[13].Descriptor.ShaderRegister = 3; //ToLight
    pd3dRootParameters[13].Descriptor.RegisterSpace = 0;
    pd3dRootParameters[13].ShaderVisibility = D3D12_SHADER_VISIBILITY_ALL;
    

    D3D12_STATIC_SAMPLER_DESC pd3dSamplerDescs[4];

    pd3dSamplerDescs[0].Filter = D3D12_FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR;
    pd3dSamplerDescs[0].AddressU = D3D12_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_MODE_WRAP;
    pd3dSamplerDescs[0].AddressV = D3D12_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_MODE_WRAP;
    pd3dSamplerDescs[0].AddressW = D3D12_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_MODE_WRAP;
    pd3dSamplerDescs[0].MipLODBias = 0;
    pd3dSamplerDescs[0].MaxAnisotropy = 1;
    pd3dSamplerDescs[0].ComparisonFunc = D3D12_COMPARISON_FUNC_ALWAYS;
    pd3dSamplerDescs[0].MinLOD = 0;
    pd3dSamplerDescs[0].MaxLOD = D3D12_FLOAT32_MAX;
    pd3dSamplerDescs[0].ShaderRegister = 0;
    pd3dSamplerDescs[0].RegisterSpace = 0;
    pd3dSamplerDescs[0].ShaderVisibility = D3D12_SHADER_VISIBILITY_PIXEL;

    pd3dSamplerDescs[1].Filter = D3D12_FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR;
    pd3dSamplerDescs[1].AddressU = D3D12_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_MODE_CLAMP;
    pd3dSamplerDescs[1].AddressV = D3D12_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_MODE_CLAMP;
    pd3dSamplerDescs[1].AddressW = D3D12_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_MODE_CLAMP;
    pd3dSamplerDescs[1].MipLODBias = 0;
    pd3dSamplerDescs[1].MaxAnisotropy = 1;
    pd3dSamplerDescs[1].ComparisonFunc = D3D12_COMPARISON_FUNC_ALWAYS;
    pd3dSamplerDescs[1].MinLOD = 0;
    pd3dSamplerDescs[1].MaxLOD = D3D12_FLOAT32_MAX;
    pd3dSamplerDescs[1].ShaderRegister = 1;
    pd3dSamplerDescs[1].RegisterSpace = 0;
    pd3dSamplerDescs[1].ShaderVisibility = D3D12_SHADER_VISIBILITY_PIXEL;

    pd3dSamplerDescs[2].Filter = D3D12_FILTER_COMPARISON_MIN_MAG_LINEAR_MIP_POINT;
    pd3dSamplerDescs[2].AddressU = D3D12_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_MODE_BORDER;
    pd3dSamplerDescs[2].AddressV = D3D12_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_MODE_BORDER;
    pd3dSamplerDescs[2].AddressW = D3D12_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_MODE_BORDER;
    pd3dSamplerDescs[2].MipLODBias = 0.0f;
    pd3dSamplerDescs[2].MaxAnisotropy = 1;
    pd3dSamplerDescs[2].ComparisonFunc = D3D12_COMPARISON_FUNC_LESS_EQUAL; //D3D12_COMPARISON_FUNC_LESS
    pd3dSamplerDescs[2].BorderColor = D3D12_STATIC_BORDER_COLOR_OPAQUE_WHITE;  //D3D12_STATIC_BORDER_COLOR_OPAQUE_BLACK;
    pd3dSamplerDescs[2].MinLOD = 0;
    pd3dSamplerDescs[2].MaxLOD = D3D12_FLOAT32_MAX;
    pd3dSamplerDescs[2].ShaderRegister = 2;//
    pd3dSamplerDescs[2].RegisterSpace = 0;
    pd3dSamplerDescs[2].ShaderVisibility = D3D12_SHADER_VISIBILITY_PIXEL;

    pd3dSamplerDescs[3].Filter = D3D12_FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR;
    pd3dSamplerDescs[3].AddressU = D3D12_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_MODE_BORDER;
    pd3dSamplerDescs[3].AddressV = D3D12_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_MODE_BORDER;
    pd3dSamplerDescs[3].AddressW = D3D12_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_MODE_BORDER;
    pd3dSamplerDescs[3].MipLODBias = 0.0f;
    pd3dSamplerDescs[3].MaxAnisotropy = 1;
    pd3dSamplerDescs[3].ComparisonFunc = D3D12_COMPARISON_FUNC_ALWAYS;
    pd3dSamplerDescs[3].BorderColor = D3D12_STATIC_BORDER_COLOR_OPAQUE_BLACK;
    pd3dSamplerDescs[3].MinLOD = 0;
    pd3dSamplerDescs[3].MaxLOD = D3D12_FLOAT32_MAX;
    pd3dSamplerDescs[3].ShaderRegister = 3;//
    pd3dSamplerDescs[3].RegisterSpace = 0;
    pd3dSamplerDescs[3].ShaderVisibility = D3D12_SHADER_VISIBILITY_PIXEL;

    D3D12_ROOT_SIGNATURE_FLAGS d3dRootSignatureFlags = D3D12_ROOT_SIGNATURE_FLAG_ALLOW_INPUT_ASSEMBLER_INPUT_LAYOUT | D3D12_ROOT_SIGNATURE_FLAG_DENY_HULL_SHADER_ROOT_ACCESS | D3D12_ROOT_SIGNATURE_FLAG_DENY_DOMAIN_SHADER_ROOT_ACCESS | D3D12_ROOT_SIGNATURE_FLAG_DENY_GEOMETRY_SHADER_ROOT_ACCESS;
    D3D12_ROOT_SIGNATURE_DESC d3dRootSignatureDesc;
    ::ZeroMemory(&d3dRootSignatureDesc, sizeof(D3D12_ROOT_SIGNATURE_DESC));
    d3dRootSignatureDesc.NumParameters = _countof(pd3dRootParameters);
    d3dRootSignatureDesc.pParameters = pd3dRootParameters;
    d3dRootSignatureDesc.NumStaticSamplers = _countof(pd3dSamplerDescs);
    d3dRootSignatureDesc.pStaticSamplers = pd3dSamplerDescs;
    d3dRootSignatureDesc.Flags = d3dRootSignatureFlags;

    ID3DBlob* pd3dSignatureBlob = NULL;
    ID3DBlob* pd3dErrorBlob = NULL;
    D3D12SerializeRootSignature(&d3dRootSignatureDesc, D3D_ROOT_SIGNATURE_VERSION_1, &pd3dSignatureBlob, &pd3dErrorBlob);
    pd3dDevice->CreateRootSignature(0, pd3dSignatureBlob->GetBufferPointer(), pd3dSignatureBlob->GetBufferSize(), __uuidof(ID3D12RootSignature), (void**)&pd3dGraphicsRootSignature);
    if (pd3dSignatureBlob) pd3dSignatureBlob->Release();
    if (pd3dErrorBlob) pd3dErrorBlob->Release();

    return(pd3dGraphicsRootSignature);
}
```

D3D12 ERROR: ID3D12Device::CreateGraphicsPipelineState: Root Signature doesn't match Vertex Shader: Shader CBV descriptor range (BaseShaderRegister=6, NumDescriptors=1, RegisterSpace=0) is not fully bound in root signature

How can I fix this error?

I have attached the project.
Please check it once while you are busy.

https://kpuackr-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/dbzho8383_tukorea_ac_kr/ES5uDcLONmVKk78-1opt2B0B8C-JYgRX9vz2jfmfKDfSjA?e=sy87Qh

I want the shadows to be rendered.

D3D12 ERROR: ID3D12Device::CreateGraphicsPipelineState: Root Signature doesn't match Vertex Shader: Shader CBV descriptor range (BaseShaderRegister=6, NumDescriptors=1, RegisterSpace=0) is not fully bound in root signature

I would like to resolve this error.

Comment: Well you didnt show the whole code, it seems like you are using some constant buffer at register 6, but I don't see it anywhere in your root signature creation

Comment: https://github.com/yoon-0012/stackOverflow.git

thank you for the reply
This is the github address of my project
Please check once

Comment: Does this even compile? Bit fields can only be of integral types. `float` bit fields are not part of standard behavior; is this a specific extension!?

Comment: @Red.Wave these are not bitfields, it's HLSL semantics

Comment: @mateeeeeee so that is a none-standard extension with poorly designed syntax. The could've used attribute syntax instead.

Comment: @Red.Wave I don't understand what do you mean. It's not C/C++ code. It's HLSL code. I am not commenting on the design.

Comment: @mateeeeeee then why is it tagged C++, if totally irrelevant. Otherwise the OP could at least mark and separate C++ and HLSL parts.

Comment: @Red.Wave well it's not irrelevant if the part of the relevant code is in C++. OP did specify that one part is shader code and the other one is root signature creation which is in C++.

Comment: @mateeeeeee good. Now I can not sees the relationship between the 2 snippets. No similar ID/literal ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to change your 14th root parameter's register from this

```
pd3dRootParameters[13].Descriptor.ShaderRegister = 3; //ToLight
```

To

```
 pd3dRootParameters[13].Descriptor.ShaderRegister = 6; //ToLight
```

Because that cbuffer is on `register(b6)`. Alternatively, change your register of that cbuffer to `register(b3)`.